# Multifunctioning in Javascript (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

The **concept** is running multiple functions concurrently.

The **reason** is, I have a page which performs various actions through ajax. These actions includes making multiple backups of new files uploaded in the upload directory. But I want this process to be initiated by a moderator.

As this is a very lengthy process(might even take hours to complete), it blocks others ajax requests from executing, until this process complete.

I want to execute functions along with the previously executed function parallelly.

I am using jQuery's Ajax to sent initiate the request.

I will try to explain using a example

---

I use ajax  request to perform a server side action. These requests are initiation on click event of a anchor text.

```
$(".ajax").live('click',function() {
     action = $(this).attr['rel'];
     $.post(
         'proccess.php',
         { action: action }, //among many action one is for the backup
         function(data) {
            //once a particular action is complete check the data to decide if it requires to continue
            flag = data.flag;
            // if the action fails or if action is backup then the flag is true
            if(flag) {
                //reexecute the same function
                $(this).trigger('click');
            }
         },'json'
     );
});
```

In the case if action=='Backup', it backups one file at a time then responds to the script with the json with a true flag and success message to notify about the progress and reexecutes the same function.

Where as other actions will include actions to view the backup log, errors, and other actions that are not even related backup.

So once I click the backup option to initiate the backup progress, I cannot execute other actions

But I am using trigger to initiate another request because if multiple function trigger is pending and the function has finished backing up one file then before sending another call of same function it executes the pending function execution first.

---

But I need a better solution, and for that I need to execute multiple instances of a same function many times.

Comment: Aren't your AJAX requests asynchronous? They shouldn't block anything else.

Comment: The problem is not AJAX, it is about `**EXECUTING DIFFERENT FUNCTION IN JAVASCRIPT AT A SAME TIME**`

Comment: It's hard to figure out seeing nothing of your code. You *cannot* launch JavaScript code in the background but the AJAX bottleneck you describe should not be happening since browsers implement XMLHttpRequest in native (asynchronous) code.

Comment: @Alvaro, I updated my question with a small example and more explanation of my existing solution

Comment: `action` and `flag` are global (thus shared) variables, is that intended?

Comment: In my case, it is just variables holding crucial piece of information.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like this would be better designed with the concurrency on the server side.
Have your ajax request start the backup, and immediately return (with like a "backup process started" message)

You can then query the server every minute or so to see how the process is going.
That way each ajax request will be over in milliseconds, freeing the client up to do whatever else you need.

Comment: Is the ajax request uploading huge amounts of data to the server? or is it just initiating the backup and waiting for it to finish? If it's just waiting for the backup to finish, then you should instead do the backup in a separate thread, and allow the ajax request to finish quickly.

Comment: Yes, It is just initiating a backup at seperate page and waiting for it to finish. I am using ajax to backup the files on the system this also including uploading files. I am confused about what you said "do the backup in the seperate thread", I also need to notify the user once a particular file in backed up successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Educated guess: you are using PHP in the server backend and your PHP are using sessions. If so, you should read the necessary session data and issue a call to `session_write_close()` as soon as possible. That way, the session file is no longer locked and can be used by other concurrent calls.

**Update:** If you say that question is not related to AJAX, then the answer is: you cannot.

However, if strictly necessary you may be able to simulate the feature playing with DOM and event handlers.

Comment: I think I made it unclear, while I am executing one function... I need to execute another function before the previous function completes or returns anything